# Dell XPS laptop BIOS complains after installing SSD

Tags: boot, ssd, bios, dell-xps

I installed a Samsung 830 SSD in my XPS L501X and now every time it boots, after the logo screen it beeps twice, rattles the DVD drive and displays this message (and nothing else)

```
Press <F1> to continue......
Press <F2> to enter SETUP
Press <F12> to enter Boot Menu
```

Pressing any key except <kbd>K2</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> continues the boot and nothing seems wrong.

In other cases this are shown below an error message and the usual solution is to disable boot errors, but the PhoenixBios (v. A08) in this laptop has no such options, just the usual boot devices, security and switches for built-in devices.

Can I get it to display an error message? Or at least stop signalling the error?

Answer (score 1):

A 2 Beep code means that the Dell Machine encountered an error with one or more of the memory chipsets. Since it allowed you to continue booting at least one must be seated properly, but the second could be loose or malfunctioning. Try unseating and reseating your memory chips and see if that clears it up.

If that does not work you'll need to run a pass through the Dell Diagnostics test to get a more detailed error report.

Comment: I have 2x 4GB modules, everything reports and appears to use all 8GB, are there situations where memory errors are reported but the memory is still used?

Comment: Warning level error - although those are usually pretty rare. Have you used the Dell Diagnostic test yet?